# MDA : Model Driven Architecture

Tags: java, model, eclipse-emf, mda, metamodel

Need a idea for developing very simple application demonstrating concepts of MDA.

Comment: How about "hello, world!"? :) The question is very vague actually..

Comment: @Vincenzo, its plain simple.. I want to study benifits of MDA applied to real world solution, its pros and cons.

Comment: [MDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-driven_architecture) can be applied to any application, no matter how simple/complex it is. The more complex the app you're designing the less effective is your demonstration of MDA.

Comment: I agree and I just want to evaluate. Let me take the first step !

Comment: If you want to study the benefits of MDA, read a book, and then apply it to your next project if you feel its worth it. MDA is a man-made methodology, and just hacking away it on your own won't help much. Learn as you read, read as you learn.

Answer (score 4):

Alright, it is hard to find something analogous to a hello world in MDA world as MDA is geared on solving a bigger problem. The best way in my opinion to get started is to approach the below problem by "thinking in meta-**model**"

In any real world application, there are certain artifacts that you require for any business entity to be persisted. Pick 2 such simple entities like Customer and Orders and generate all the corresponding artifacts across all the layers of any multi-tiered application (like ui, persistence etc). Below are the artifacts to get you started

1. UI (jsf form, managed bean,
   faces-congig.xml) for the user to
   enter data for both the entities
2. Servie later artifacts like
   transaction decmarcation code etc
3. Persistence layer artifacts like
   (DAO/Repository, JPA/Hibernate
   mapping file)

Now in the process you will also identify that there are more things to model like faces-config, jpa/hibernate config etc..

[EMF](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/) is the more prevalent toolkit for meta-modling and [oAW](http://www.eclipse.org/workinggroups/oaw/) is your generation/transformation engine. [This tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseEMF/article.html) can get you started.

[Spring Roo](http://www.openxava.org/web/guest/mda) and [OpenXava](http://www.openxava.org/web/guest/mda) are in my opinion two well know frameworks that supports MDA

*Get ready to loose yourself in the MDA jargon of meta-model, meta-meta model, model instance etc...*

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the previous answer,
I would just add some more info. 
The Eclipse Modeling Framework is, in my opinion, one of the best framework implementing the OMG architecture and languages. I suggest you to use TopCased for modeling (http://www.topcased.org) it is based on EMF and provides you a good IDE for UML/SYSML modeling. You therefore might want to automatically generate some code from your models. To this end I strongly suggest you Acceleo which is an EMF compliant implementation of the MOF Models 2 Text Transformation Language and related engine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, "hello world": create class "World" and define operation "hello" on it. If that is not enough, you can extend "World" as you wish.