# Java/UML Programming

Tags: java, uml

I was on YouTube learning something new called UML programming.

I made my own example through code in Java but how would it look like if it was "digital UML"?

While understanding how this means in terms of Java and from the UML aspect, I have no idea what "digital UML" means.

Below is what I have tried so far:

```
class Insect
{
}

class Ant extends Insect
{
}

class Spider extends Insect
{
}

class Butterfly extends Insect
{
}

class CarpenterAnt extends Ant
{
}

class FireAnt extends Ant
{
}

class BlackWidow extends Spider
{
}

class Tarantula extends Spider
{
}

class Monarch extends Butterfly
{
}

class SwallowTail extends Butterfly
{
}

class EasternBlack extends SwallowTail
{
}

class PipeBrush extends SwallowTail
{
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by digital UML?

Comment: See [Stack Overflow: Is model driven architecture worth it and what is the state of the art in the tooling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523258/is-model-driven-architecture-worth-it-and-what-is-the-state-of-the-art-in-the-to) and [Stack Overflow: MDA : Model Driven Architecture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479883/mda-model-driven-architecture) as this is probably close to what the (anonymous) youtube bloggers might call "digital UML". Both questions are few years old, so the nowadays state of affairs may be slightly different

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking at all.

Comment: Could you please give use some reference: a hyperlink, a book, ... ?

Comment: UML in general is not a new thing, and generating code from models has been around for even longer. Anyway, no question in sight, voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to think of a response as possible for an academic but it will not be easy.

Let us start from the fact that there is something called "digital UML". If there is something called UML.

Talk of UML in depth requires much time. In a curse of any University, I'd say at least a semester.

To keep it short, UML is a modeling language. A visual language used to represent different diagrams the elements of the software.
UML offers many types of diagrams. Each is designed to represent the software from a "view" in particular.

UML was born with the idea of standardizing the various proposals to illustrate the classes, relationships, and how to communicate with each other. Today it enjoys a good expansion and acceptance.

I suggest that you go to good reading; at least two books:
Applying UML and Patterns: An Introduction to Object-Oriented Analysis and Design and Iterative Development. Craig Larman.
UML dropwise. Martin Fowler, Kendall Scott.

Returning to the term "digital". I think the YouTube user has invented a joke or play with ignorance believing it can bring more than he can.

For you code of example, in UML (Class Diagram) you see a class "Insect" and others that inherit from it.

Comment: I understand :) Thank you for taking the time to make a explanation for me to know this. I really appreciate it!!